# use date as new filename of my pdf file RESLOVE

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

how can i create a copy of a pdf file and rename it as the current date and time i try this code but its saying that unsupported format

```
If (Not System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files\BP_Integrated_Technologiest_Inc\Email\")) Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(txtpdf.Text, "C:\Program Files\BP_Integrated_Technologiest_Inc\Email\" & pdfID & "." & DateTime.Now & ".pdf", Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
    End If
```

Comment: You cannot have special characters in filenames. What you can do is format the current date and time to yyyyMMddHHmmss. This will format the date for example, May 26, 2017 10:34:12 AM as 20170526103412.

Comment: Your code converts `DateTime.Now` to a string using your culture's default format. Apparently that format includes characters that are not allowed in file names. Use the `ToString` method to convert the date and time to a string that only contains valid characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formatting the date first with something like:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")
```

That will get a string like '201726052230' 
You can format it as you like take a look at some of the formats here:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub main()
    Console.WriteLine(Now)
    Console.WriteLine(File_Friendly_date(Now))
End Sub
Function File_Friendly_date(date_ As Date) As String
    Return date_.ToShortDateString.Replace("/", "-")
End Function
```